# Converting coordinate decimal degree of polyline to UTM using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arctoolbox

Currently I have a polyline shapefile that has decimal degree coordinate (Geographic Coordinate System), however I am going to change it to UTM (Projected Coordinate System) using ArcMap.

Does ArcMap has a tool to convert this coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "[project tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm)". This will reproject your dataset into another coordinate system. This tool will create a new version of the dataset into the required CRS.

If you just need to change the dataframes reference system, you can do this by right-clicking the dataframe > properties> coordinate system. This will change the dataframe only. Please see this [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/specifying-a-coordinate-system.htm) for more information.

Comment: You have referenced ArcGIS Pro documentation when the user is using the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture.

Comment: @MacroZED : I've been trying as your suggestion, however unfortunately the polyline shapefile still has coordinate value of decimal degree, what I am trying actually is to transform the coordinate value from decimal degree to meter (utm), since it is a polyline definetely it has infinite of coordinate points, therefore I need some tool to change it by automatically.

Comment: You need to edit the question, as that is not what youre asking. Once you reproject it, then you can calculate the X/Yvalues into metres.

Comment: An esri polyline does not have infinite points, only a finite series of points that comprise the polyline. If you tried the "change the data frame's coordinate system", you may need to also change the display's units. Data frame properties > general tab > display units. If you need a permanent version of data in UTM, use the [Project tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm).

Comment: @ MacroZED : Thank you so much for your precious input to my problem :) , I don't know why, sometimes I always get issue in the GIS coordinate part. Anyway I will let you know if the issue is solved. Thanks :) –